# Run .Net Runtime Optimization Service

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-installation, .net-framework

I want to make the .Net Runtime Optimization Service run after a fresh install of Windows.

How do I do that?

Comment: Start > Services and go look for it. Enable it.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks. But I don't see it there even though I ran it (Services) as admin. Maybe it has some different "official" name?

Comment: Have you installed it?

Answer (score 1):

Open up a command prompt and `cd` to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`, from there run `mscorsvw.exe`.

If `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` doesn't exist in your system, or your `%windir%` isn't `C:\Windows` then browse your `%windir%` for an appropriate .Net Framework folder and run the `mscorsvw.exe` from there.